# WordPress, Woocommerce Attributes Value(s) input field type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a web-site using WordPress and WooCommerce.

I have the attributes for products: Length, Width, Height.

Can I change the type of input field to "number" for value(s) for these attributes?

Is it even possible to do? Is there a general some hook to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There is a plugin for that.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't need new field for product.
I want to know is it possible to change type of input field Value(s) for specific attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I was breaking my head for a while with this and in the end i found that native select input type which woocommerce has actually does the job.

The only downside is that you need to manually enter your values and later pick them from dropdwon menu.

Hope the answer helps.